# Parse Datetime string

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I'm trying to convert the following string to datetime. I've searched high and low and can't find the exact formats string and I don't want to resort to parsing it manually.

```
var dateString = "20110828T134108+0100";
```

All my attempts fail with FormatException.

Comment: What format strings have you tried?

Comment: I tried first to remove the timezone so the string became "20110828T134108" and tried `DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "yyyyMMdd'T'hhmmss",null)` but with no luck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
var date = DateTime.ParseExact( dateString
   ,"yyyyMMdd\THHmmsszzz"
   ,CultureInfo.InvariantCulture 
   );
```

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx):

> If format is a custom format pattern that does not include date or
>   time separators (such as "yyyyMMdd HHmm"), use the invariant culture
>   for the provider parameter and the widest form of each custom format
>   specifier. For example, if you want to specify hours in the format
>   pattern, specify the wider form, "HH", instead of the narrower form,
>   "H".

Answer (score 0):

The documentation on the format string is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

That should get you started. :)

Answer (score 0):

try this format: `"yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss"`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("20110828T134108+0100", "yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmsszzzz", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```