# Parse DateTime using C#

Tags: c#, .net, string, datetime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Parse Datetime string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9434336/parse-datetime-string)

I'm trying to parse the following DateTime in C#:

```
string date = "Wed Jul 25 19:41:36 2012 +0200"
DateTime result = DateTime.Parse(date);
```

And I'm getting the following error:

```
System.FormatException : String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
```

Anybody knows what is the problem here?

Comment: @PeterRitchie Definite duplicate if you ignore the format, I've personally answered 3 of these now, but *technically* the format has changed each time :-)

Comment: Not sure why people are closing as duplicate... telling the OP that parse strings *exist* doesn't answer the entire question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `DateTime.ParseExact()` for that. For example

UPDATED:

```
string dateString = "Your date";
string format = "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy %K";
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, format, 
              CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Console.WriteLine(dateTime);
```

**[Documentation Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx)** and `DateTime` string formatting options [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx).

**[You can also view here {Complr.com}](https://compilr.com/johntotetwoo/datetimeparseexact/main.cs)**

Comment: Not to be picky, as that is very close, but it doesn't cater for the time-zone offset that the OP has included.

Comment: I just updated the answer after some research. sorry for the first one.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I will accept your answer, you was the first ...

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth thank you for the link on formats.. i upvoted your answer too.

Comment: @John No problem, ditto after the edit :-)

Answer (score 6):

You need to specify the parsing format as that is non-standard. `DateTime.ParseExact` allows you to specify the format.

Something like this will work, <strike>however I've yet to verify if that time-zone part is working correctly, seems to give me a date/time at 1800 hrs...</strike> Ah this is because where I am it is BST (GMT +1).

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string date = "Wed Jul 25 19:41:36 2012 +0200";
        string format = "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy %K";
        //string format = "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy zzz"; // Also works.
        DateTime dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(date, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

`DateTime` string formatting options are documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx), you can create a parse string using any combination of these to parse a `DateTime` successfully.

Another example of this can be found here: [Parse DateTime From Odd Format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11473523/parse-datetime-from-odd-format/11473602#11473602)