# Parse MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss string to DateTime in C#

Tags: c#, datetime

I am having a problem parsing a string to DateTime. I get the string like this from another system:

```
7/30/2021 12:00:00 AM
```

So I am trying to parse it like this but I get an error that the format could not be detected:

```
string s = "7/30/2021 12:00:00 AM";
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(s, "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Minutes: `mi` → `mm`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parse DateTime using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11672793/parse-datetime-using-c-sharp)

Comment: @MrFuppes almost right, just one M for months _"M/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt"_

Comment: Thanks for the hint, Ondrej! I edited that in my orignal post. Unfortunately, it still does not work. I also tried "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt" and it does not work either.

Comment: HH for hours right? Instead of hh.

Comment: I tried "M/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss" and "M/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt" now, but both do not work.

Comment: `M/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt`. Use only 1 M as your month with only 1 number. https://dotnetfiddle.net/3MxRCb

Comment: @Malawirel why did you change to HH?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it to work with what Yong Shun suggested.

```
string s = "7/30/2021 12:00:00 AM";
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(s, "M/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: If you check with the 3th of July (`7/3/2021`), you should use `M/d/yyyy` as date format.

Answer (score 1):

*(You have already found your solution, which is great. This answer is meant to provide general guidance to others with similar problems.)*

Your input (`7/30/2021 12:00:00 AM`) does not match the format string (`MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss`). For example, your input contains the string `AM`, which does not correspond to any pattern in your format string.

The solution is to read the following page very carefully:

- [Custom date and time format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings)

and ensure that

1. you understand what every placeholder means (for example `MM` is a two-digit month, not a one-or-two-digit month, which would be `M`) and that
2. your input matches your format string.

To debug your problem and find out what you are missing, you can try to performe the *reverse* operation: Execute `DateTime.Now.ToString(format)` with your format string and see if it matches your input. If it doesn't, something still needs tweaking.

Answer (score 0):

You may give a try like this

```
string s = "7/30/2021 12:00:00 AM";    
Convert.ToDateTime(s, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```